# What is the right way to convert EBNF to BNF when using GLR parser?

Tags: parsing, glr

EBNF like this

```
Goal = Stmt
Stmt = "if" "expr" "then" Stmt ("else" Stmt)?
Stmt = "S"
```

Should I Convert this to

```
Goal = Stmt
X = "else" Stmt
Stmt = "if" "expr" "then" Stmt | "if" "expr" "then" Stmt X 
Stmt = "S"
```

Or

```
Goal = Stmt
Stmt = "if" "expr" "then" Stmt | "if" "expr" "then" Stmt "else" Stmt
Stmt = "S"
```

Are these two BNF mean the same to GLR parser?

------------------------ APPEND CONTENT ------------------------------

If the lexes are

```
"if" "expr" "then" "if" "expr" "then" "S" "else" "S"
```

GLR parser should get two trees

```
Goal
    Stmt
        "if"
        "expr"
        "then"
        Stmt
            "if"
            "expr"
            "then"
            Stmt
                "S"
        "else"
        Stmt
            "S"
```

And

```
Goal
    Stmt
        "if"
        "expr"
        "then"
        Stmt
            "if"
            "expr"
            "then"
            Stmt
                "S"
            "else"
             Stmt
                "S"
```

But the first converted BNF can only get the first tree, because when it meet `"else"`, there is no conflict in reduce/shift, the conflict is at meeting X.

The second BNF will has a reduce/shift conflict when it meet `"else"`, so the parser will split to two threads to parse in different conditions.

Am I right? Is there any ACTION, GOTO TABLE generator that will treat the first BNF just like the second one?

Comment: problem solved, the first converted BNF can generate the second tree. Only if you generate the right Action table.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent grammars and will parse the same language.

Your grammar with X only uses X in one place.  The net effect is as if the body of X was substituted where X is referenced.  In practice, having the X production will force the parser to do a bit more work.  Unless you want to attach a semantic action to the reduction for X, that additional work isn't buying anything in efficiency.

To the extent that having such use-once production makes the grammar more maintainable, this is useful to do.  In a small grammar like this, I don't see the point.  In practical grammars (we have a GLR grammar for IBM COBOL with 5000 productions [blame IBM, not us]), such structuring can be pretty helpful and the additional parsing overhead doesn't matter.

Comment: I append an example to explain why I am confused. I think the two BNF are not equivalent grammars.